# Pakistan Job offered by Recurter based in UK for job location KSA

Tags: job-offer

If an employer offer a job to employee, and sign a contract and process all documentation and agreed on joining date. and an employee resigned based on job offer and contract sign.... then Employer go back and withdraw the job offer... what should be the legal action against employer and where to take this legal action.. please share your expert opinion.
Thanks

Comment: KSA = Kingdom of Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Did you pay any money during the recruiting process? A UK recruiter for a job in KSA sounds a bit suspicious.

Comment: No direct payment to recruiter.... payment made to visa agent for visa stamping and for flight ticket which was supposed to be refund after joining.

Comment: Where are you actually based at the moment, is it Pakistan?

Comment: I think you got scammed. (And please add this additional information to your question). http://www.thenational.ae/uae/technology/warning-to-uae-job-seekers-about-bogus-recruitment-scams Where did you apply?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply...I am based in Pakistan,   I am sure it not scam, I am looking for legal action against the employer

Comment: Why are you sure? Where did you apply?

Comment: they issue me proper work visa.

Comment: I need your expert opinion, where and how to challenge the Employer.

Comment: visa is of KSA not UK, and it was issued in KSA embassy..

Comment: @AQkhan I am not sure but would local police help?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could have been scammed. Paying money up front to a UK recruiter for a job in the KSA is a huge red flag and there are similar scams going on: [UAE job scam](http://www.thenational.ae/uae/technology/warning-to-uae-job-seekers-about-bogus-recruitment-scams)

So I fear there is not much you can do in this case (that will bring your money back).